# Nesting too deep exception ATG

Tags: json, rest, atg, atg-dynamo

I am getting following Exception while trying to invoke my customized Actor chain  :

`CONTAINER:atg.service.response.output.OutputException:      atg.service.filter.bean.Resources-   >atg.service.response.output.JSONOutputCustomizer.errorUnableToGetPropertyValue; SOURCE:atg.json.JSONException: Nesting too deep. atg.service.filter.bean.Resources->atg.service.response.output.JSONOutputCustomizer.errorUnableToGetPropertyValue`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the value of the `MaxNestingDepth` in the component for `/atg/dynamo/service/response/output/JSONOutputCustomizer`. The default value is 15. If you make it -1 it will be 'unlimited'.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_03/Platform.11-1/ATGWSFrameGuide/html/s0505configuringrestmvcoutput01.html) is a reference to the docs for arguably the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already tried the same . Though after deeper analysis I made out that the actual issue was the cycling formation in my code

Comment: Cool. If you provided a bit more detail in the original question, chances are we would have been able to help a bit more too. The error on its own wasn't much to go on. Glad you sorted it.